# Dozer deep mapping object to map

Tags: java, mapping, dozer

Can dozer do deep mapping complex object to map? 
For example, I have object

```
class A {
    String aField;
    List<B> listOfBs;
}

class B {
    C cField;
}

class C {
    String fieldInC;
}
```

In result I need the following map:

```
{
aField: 'aFieldValie', 
listOfBs.0.cField.fieldInC: 'firstFieldInCValue', 
listOfBs.1.cField.fieldInC: 'secondFieldInCValue', 
}
```

I don't need the map strongly in this format, I need the map which dozer can convert into the object later.